# Right-click on a MacBook Pro running Windows 7?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I've got a Macbook Pro whizzing it's way through the postal system towards me which I intend to run Mac OS X and Windows 7 On.

I was wondering how the MacBook Pro does right clicks in windows, I'm lead to believe that clicking with two fingers rather than one will right click in Mac OS but does the same apply to Windows on a MacBook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 7 running in bootcamp:

To right-click using a trackpad:
Place three fingers on the trackpad and click the trackpad button.

Just make sure you install the Bootcamp drivers that are on the OS X Installation DVD

Comment: what if I don't have trackpad?

Comment: ...All macbooks have a trackpad.

Comment: Oh, and I am pretty sure it works with just two fingers, exactly like it does in OS X (as long as you have the drivers installed)